# Simple Unity Launcher Fix

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, launcher, themes

I see that I can install 'myunity', and that seems like it will be overkill for my problem.

Here is what happened:

I was using 2 monitors with different desktop backgrounds using nitrogen, and the unity launcher was colored the prevailing color of my backgrounds (great).

Then, I added a third monitor.  When I did that, things got a little screwed up, because I had to unplug everything, plug it back in...and I plugged in the wrong hdmi cable...anyways, got it sorted out; all the resolutions correct...and then got nitrogen set up with a different desktop for each monitor.

Only problem is that now the unity launcher (vertical portion on the left side) is this annoying original ubuntu pink/purple, even though the rest of the theme is silver.

How do I force the unity launcher to take on the right color?

(I found the 'Appearence' section, changed the theme, but no luck)

Here is a screenshot (the wall paper is all black and white; no color):

[image]

Comment: There should be a setting for that via compiz config settings manager ,I'll check thatband let you know. Um, if you'd like , i can add a manual way of setting the color

Comment: Hi bordeo, what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @JacobVlijm hey, the os is 15.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple solution

Install  `Unity Tweak Tool` and under launcher settings select `Colour: Based on Wallpaper` option

[image]

#### Command-line solution

There is a `dconf` schema that corresponds to the color of the launcher.

```
/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/background-color
```

The colors are  32-bit hex values. The last byte ( two numbers ) stand for the color on which the launcher is based. `ff` means solid color defined by the other bytes, `00` means based on wallpaper.

You can run

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/background-color "'#00000000'"
```

to make color based on background

*Note* that `gsettings` is preferred for such actions. Both `dconf` and `gsettings` do the same thing, except that `gsettings` has sanity checks, but in my experience I've not ran into any issues with `dconf` and been using it successfully to alter all sorts of functionalities.

I frequently alter the color via command line, so I use the following function in my `.bashrc`:

```
unity_launcher_color()
{
  key="/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/background-color"
  hex_string=\'\#$1\'
#  echo $hex_string
  dconf write "$key" "$hex_string"
}
```

To make launcher black , call the function as so

```
 unity_launcher_color 000000ff
```

Comment: We've discussed this before, but you really shouldn't suggest people to use `dconf write`,  (use `gsetings set` instead) and the key you are referring to does not exist in 16.04 (if he is using that)

Comment: @JacobVlijm by default it doesn't exist, if it's written to, then it will be created, and color will be set. If you want I can provide screenshot of my VM right now.  As for `dconf`  ,  tons of people used without issue. I just don't see a reason why it's being criticized ?

Comment: Like earlier discussed in chat, `gsettings` provides integrity checks, and protects the `dconf` database, while writing directly to `dconf` does not. The same argument you are using now is used by people "I always used `sudo nautilus`,  tons of people do, I don't see why I wouldn't". Adding a non-existent key is an attempt to fix what is broken without fixing. obviously something went wrong in the current settings.